# Returning all items on a MySQL join, not just ones that are matching

Tags: mysql, join

checkouts

```
| item_id | user_id |
```

items

```
| item_id |
```

I want a query that will return **ALL THE ITEMS** with a column that if it exists in checkouts for a particular user_id, it returns a 1. Otherwise it will return a 0.

```
select * 
from checkouts
right join items on items.item_id = checkouts.item_id
where checkouts.user_id = 10
```

The problem is that it only returns items that it joins on, not ALL the items.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about...

```
SELECT i.item_id, c.user_id, IF(c.user_id IS NULL, 0, 1) AS extra_column
FROM items i
LEFT JOIN checkouts c ON (c.item_id = i.item_id AND c.user_id = 10)
```

Comment: won't work. you need `c.user_id is null` as one of the conditions... otherwise, `left join` is pointless.

Comment: you could also add that condition on the `on` clause and it should work I guess:  `on (c.item_id = i.tiem_id and c.user_id = 10)`

Comment: @PabloSantaCruz, yes, thanks for catching that. updated per your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Try a `left outer join`:

```
select * from items left outer join checkouts using (item_id)
 where checkouts.user_id is null or checkouts.user_id = 10
```

Alternatively you can also use:

```
select * from items i 
  left outer join checkouts c
    on (i.item_id=c.item_id and c.user_id=10)
```

Answer (score 1):

try a `right outer join`, e.g.

```
select * 
from checkouts c
right outer join items i on i.item_id = c.item_id
where c.user_id = 10
```